# making a UUID (rfc4122) what namespace for hashing full content?

Tags: node.js, sha1, uuid

I'm learning to write blog software, so I read up on Atom which requires a unique ID. Seems like what you're supposed to do is a urn:uuid: type IRI.

What makes sense to me to get a globally unique identifier is to hash the content of the post.

I've written code (see below) to generate an rfc-4122-compliant UUID (version 5), except I'm not sure what to put in for the namespace.

the RFC says it's out of its scope to say what namespace I should use, and shows a few examples, none of which seem to be the right one. I googled a bit and didn't see any recommendations beyond the ones in the RFC.

The namespace is itself supposed to be a UUID, so I'm not supposed to just put in something like "hash of the entire post" as the namespace.

To generate [all but 6 bits of] a version 5 uuid, you concatenate the namespace UUID (in raw form) with your "name".

So... here's my question: Is there a namespace UUID for using the entire contents of your document as the "name"?

Or should I make a random (v4) UUID and use that as my own personal "entire post" namespace?

Or something else?

Thanks,   - Jason

P.S. I've written a UUID generator for node which is using the ns:URL namespace for now. Here's the code if you're interested:

```
// Copyright 2011 Jason Woofenden -- CC0
//
// An almost correct rfc-4122 v5 UUID generator for node (see http://node.js)
//
// To test, run this with node, then compare the out put of these:
//
//   curl http://localhost:8129/foo
//   uuid -v 5 ns:URL foo
//
// Replace "foo" with any string and they should still be the same.

var
    http = require('http'),
    crypto = require('crypto'),
    url = require('url');
    hex_high_10 = { // set the highest bit and clear the next highest
        '0': '8',
        '1': '9',
        '2': 'a',
        '3': 'b',
        '4': '8',
        '5': '9',
        '6': 'a',
        '7': 'b',
        '8': '8',
        '9': '9',
        'a': 'a',
        'b': 'b',
        'c': '8',
        'd': '9',
        'e': 'a',
        'f': 'b'
    }

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var sum = crypto.createHash('sha1');

    // namespace in raw form. FIXME using ns:URL for now, what should it be?
    sum.update(new Buffer('a6e4EZ2tEdGAtADAT9QwyA==', 'base64'));

    // add HTTP path
    sum.update(url.parse(req.url).pathname.substr(1));

    // get sha1 hash in hex form
    var uuid = sum.digest('hex');

    // format as UUID (add dashes, version bits and reserved bits)
    uuid =
        uuid.substr(0, 8) + '-' + // time_low
        uuid.substr(8, 4) + '-' + // time_mid
        '5' + // time_hi_and_version high 4 bits (version)
        uuid.substr(13, 3) + '-' + // time_hi_and_version low 4 bits (time high)
        hex_high_10[uuid.substr(16, 1)] + uuid.substr(17, 1) + // cloc_seq_hi_and_reserved
        uuid.substr(18, 2) + '-' + // clock_seq_low
        uuid.substr(20, 12); // node

    // spit it out
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end(uuid + '\n');
}).listen(8129, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8129/');
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same question some time ago and came to the conclusion that using a v4 UUID for the namespace is the right thing to do. Basically I wanted to generate an UUID from a String, and here's what I do (in Java, but it's simple enough to translate to JS):

```
public final class FooIdGen {

    /**
     * The namespace id for generating Foo - UUIDs from the foo - id
     * strings.
     */
    public final static String NAMESPACE =
            "0416141a-5229-4d16-94cc-43d546ef1118"; //NOI18N

    private final static byte[] NS_BYTES =
            uuidToBytes(UUID.fromString(NAMESPACE));

    /**
     * Generates a UUID for a given foo - id.
     *
     * @param fooId the reporter ID to get the UUID for
     * @return the UUID for the specified foo ID
     */
    public static UUID uuidForFooId(String fooId) {
        final byte[] idBytes;

        try {
            idBytes = fooId.getBytes("US-ASCII"); //NOI18N
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            /* pretty sure US-ASCII is ok, so this can't happen */
            throw new AssertionError(ex.toString());
        }

        final byte[] tmp = Arrays.copyOf(
                NS_BYTES, idBytes.length + NS_BYTES.length);

        System.arraycopy(idBytes, 0, tmp, NS_BYTES.length, idBytes.length);

        return UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(tmp);
    }

    /* want it to align, so that's ok */
    @SuppressWarnings("PointlessBitwiseExpression")
    private static byte[] uuidToBytes(UUID id) {
        final long h = id.getMostSignificantBits();
        final long l = id.getLeastSignificantBits();
        final byte[] result = new byte[16];

        int i=0;
        result[i++] = (byte) ((h >> 56) & 0xff);
        result[i++] = (byte) ((h >> 48) & 0xff);
        result[i++] = (byte) ((h >> 40) & 0xff);
        result[i++] = (byte) ((h >> 32) & 0xff);
        result[i++] = (byte) ((h >> 24) & 0xff);
        result[i++] = (byte) ((h >> 16) & 0xff);
        result[i++] = (byte) ((h >>  8) & 0xff);
        result[i++] = (byte) ((h >>  0) & 0xff);

        result[i++] = (byte) ((l >> 56) & 0xff);
        result[i++] = (byte) ((l >> 48) & 0xff);
        result[i++] = (byte) ((l >> 40) & 0xff);
        result[i++] = (byte) ((l >> 32) & 0xff);
        result[i++] = (byte) ((l >> 24) & 0xff);
        result[i++] = (byte) ((l >> 16) & 0xff);
        result[i++] = (byte) ((l >>  8) & 0xff);
        result[i++] = (byte) ((l >>  0) & 0xff);

        return result;
    }

    private FooIdGen() {
        /* no instances */
    }
}
```

Comment: @Raynos: I can't provide a JS implementation this time. Also, I think it's more about dealing with v4 UUIDs than Java or JavaScript. Good if it helps, sorry if not.

Comment: thanks! I'm glad I'm not the only one unable to find a list of [more than 4] established/suggested namespaces. P.S. Java scares me a little bit :)

Comment: this line `return UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(tmp);` does the magic all that other code is useless cruft ...

Comment: @JarrodRoberson No, `UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(tmp)` generates a type 3 UUID, the rest of the code uses that to generate type 5 UUIDs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some CoffeeScript code I use to generate a v4 UUID using the Sha-1 hash of something.  (Convert to Javascript using http://js2coffee.org.)

```
# Compute a uuid v4 from the Sha-1 hash of data.
crypto = require('crypto')
exports.uuidsha1 = (data) ->
    sha1sum = crypto.createHash('sha1')
    sha1sum.update(data)
    s = sha1sum.digest('hex')
    i = -1
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, (c) ->
        i += 1
        switch c
            when 'x'
                return s[i]
            when 'y'
                # take 8 + low order 3 bits of hex number.
                return ((parseInt('0x'+s[i],16)&0x3)|0x8).toString(16)
    )
```

Comment: Nice and compact code! But... 1) v4 uuids are supposed to be random. v5 uuids use sha1. 2) with v5 uuids, you're supposed to prepend a "namespace" uuid before hashing with sha1. 3) you're skipping a byte in s[] every time your replace() hits a dash.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out node-uuid. I'm not using it yet, but I plan to look at it closer when I need this type of feature. It may not suite your needs, but I thought you should be aware of it.
https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid

Comment: Doesn't answer my question (only generates v4 (random) uuids). But +1 because it contains some clever code and appears to be well tested... I just might use it some day.

Comment: Sorry to not provide an answer, but I too don't have one. I'm glad you found this module interesting and I was able to help you in some small way.